# How to build a SelectList from a List and a (a -> Bool)?

Tags: elm

I am using [elm-spa-example](https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-spa-example/) model and I have a `Session` that contains a `List Recipe` as well as a Model that contains a `recipeID`

I'd like to build a [SelectList](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rtfeldman/selectlist/1.0.0/SelectList) that would select the recipe that has got the RecipeID in the list.

Ideally I would use something like:

`SelectList.selectFromList : (a -> Bool) -> List a -> SelectList a`

I my case I would do:

`SelectList.selectFromList (\recipe -> recipe.id == recipeID) session.recipes`

Comment: What should happen if none or more than one calls to that function return `True`?

Comment: Only the first one is selected like the `SelectList.select` method convention

Comment: Why does `SelectList.select` not provide the utility you are after?

Comment: To be able to use `SelectList.select` you first need to convert the `List` into a `SelectList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something like that:

```
selectFromList : (a -> Bool) -> List a -> Maybe (SelectList a)
selectFromList isSelectable list = 
    case list of
        first :: rest ->
            SelectList.fromLists [] first rest
                |> SelectList.select isSelectable
                |> Just
        [] ->
            Nothing
```

I also added:

```
prev : SelectList a -> Maybe a
prev list =
    SelectList.before list
        |> List.reverse
        |> List.head


next : SelectList a -> Maybe a
next list =
    SelectList.after list
        |> List.head
```

Answer (score 1):

I put together this quick ellie that illustrates what I think are the steps needed to achieve what you want.  It's certainly not optimized or even idiomatic.

https://ellie-app.com/4TJVgSCwXa1/0

```
firstPartialList = takeWhile condition myList
selected = Maybe.withDefault "" (getAt (length firstPartialList) myList)
secondPartialList = drop ((length firstPartialList) + 1) myList

mySelectList = SelectList.fromLists firstPartialList selected secondPartialList

condition = (\item -> item /= otherItem)


myList = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

otherItem = "b"
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, thanks to you I discovered `List.Extra` and the `getAt` utility.

Comment: In this end with `List.Extra` I don't even need `SelectList` and I could just use `elemIndex` and `getAt`

Comment: Can you post the code you ended up using so that others with this issue can benefit from this question?

Comment: @Natim you should accept the answer that provided that code for you then.

Comment: I did, but you need to wait two days before being able to accept your own answer

Answer (score 0):

SelectList doesn't expose selectFromList are you sure the link is right?

Comment: Of course it doesn't exists, that's the API I'd like to use

Comment: i don't understand, if you want a list why not just use a list? a list would be something like 
    
    [1, 2] 3 [4, 5] 

not
    
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: The issue is that to be able to create the SelectList.fromLists you need two lists and something. I am populating that from a JSON.Decode and I only have a selected item later on.

Comment: I want a SelectList to be able to get a selected item and link to the previous and the next ones.